# apache2 config for domain + subdomain

Tags: apache, subdomain, config

I have three domains:

- example.com
- www.example.com
- api.example.com

And this is my config:

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

api.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName api.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I access to api.example.com, I'm going to example.com instead of real api.example.com (should be a proxy to my server)

why is my first conf matching with api.example.com? what is the problem? thanks!

Comment: Is the second configuration read at all when apache is restarted? Try putting a syntax error in there. Does it throw up?

Comment: when I disable the 000-default, my api.conf works correctly, but the example.com matches too with the api behavior